# Issues with WinFORMS Blazor

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm doing a project in windowsforms with blazor in C#, the objective is to create a login system, I have the database already connected and the implementation of blazor with winforms is already done, it's giving me an error in the program class, I think it may be related to the way I introduced blazorwebview in the form. The error I'm getting is this: InvalidOperationException: Error: No element is currently associated with component 1 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

This is the code where I connect balzorwebview to windows forms:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WindowsForms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging;

namespace Login_Forms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();
            blazorWebView1.HostPage = "wwwroot\\index.html";
            blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#app/login");

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        
    }
}
```

Razor Component:

```
@page "/login"
@using Login_Forms.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

<h3>Login</h3>

@code
{
    private Usuario loginModel = new Usuario(1, "Tiago", "12345");
}

<EditForm Model='@loginModel' OnValidSubmit='@Login'>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div>
        <label for="Username">Username:</label>
        <InputText id="Username" @bind-Value ="@loginModel.Name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
        <InputText id="Password" @bind-Value ="@loginModel.PassWord"/>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="Login">
</EditForm>

@code {
    

    private void Login()
    {
        
        bool isAuthenticated = Authenticate(loginModel.Name, loginModel.PassWord);

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("Login bem-sucedido!");
        }
        else
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("Falha no login. Credenciais inválidas.");
        }
    }

  
    private bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
       
        return username == "admin" && password == "admin";
    }
}
```

I already searched Google for the problem, unfortunately I didn't find anything, so I came to ask the community if anyone knows anything about this. I haven't tested anything

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Please provide the full error stack when asking a question. Also post your razor component

Answer (score 0):

You should change below code

```
blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Counter>("#app/login");
```

to

```
blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Login>("#app");
```

Then the issue will be fixed.

**Test Result**

Reproduce the issue.

[image]

Fix it, and it works well in my side.

[image]